# Is the trigger.io inbuilt browser always webkit?

Tags: css, trigger.io

I'm tinkering with css for my app. Am I correct in assuming that webkit specific css prefixes will always work with both Android and iOS forge-built apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways to find out during your device testing:

- if you are using jQuery then...

  forge.logging.log($.browser.webkit);
- if you are not using jQuery then parse the user agent...

  forge.logging.log(/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent));

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you can stick to webkit prefixes + no-prefix.

Vendor prefixes are a mess, opera recently announced that they will be supporting webkit prefixes, even though opera is not a webkit browser - because a lot of websites are using webkit-only prefixes... well...

If you want to get rid of prefixes all the way, (cleaner CSS) you can use PrefixFree js : http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/